# Question about install Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, filesystem

Today I tried to reinstall my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS through a USB flash, at first time I chose the default partition plan, then I found that there is no /home partition, and I think remount a /home is much more complex than installing again, apart from that,  I also ran a few shell codes to test whether my wireless network adapter worked okay(" ping 127.0.0.1". )

After that I repeat the installation, when it let me choose partition plan, I  chose 'something else', deleted all partition and disparted again.

Having finished second time installing, I start my OS and open terminal, clicked 'up', something strange happened, the history of my last time input still existed, and it seemed to be there forever.
I had deleted all partition, the history of anything should have been deleted, why it hadn't? and where is it now?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not mark the partitions to be reformatted, then "deleted" them, and overwrote the previous partitions with the same partition format (ext4 etc) then the data that was on the drive is still technically there so when you reinstall, it is theoretically possible to read the data from a previous install

Source: I have had this happen also

Comment: So how to clear it?

Comment: When you run the installer, just add the "mark for formatting" flag on each new partition and that should clear it out. If not, you can completely delete all partitions, then rebuild a new partition table from scratch. If that also doesn't work, then in the live cd you can run `gparted` and manually delete and format the partitions or the whole disk in order to erase the data, this method may take a bit of time to run though.